# Is it possible to hide VSCode's title bar on Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

The title bar which can be used to close/minmize/maxmize the window is not necessary for me, but it holds an area which is a waste.
I tried all the options I searched from Google, but none of them worked.
I'm using MacOS Montery, is it possible to hide the title bar?

Comment: Try pressing F11 for full-screen mode. It should work on any OS

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution.

Install 'CustomizeUI' plugin and add

```json
  "window.titleBarStyle": "native",
  "customizeUI.titleBar": "frameless",
```

in the setting.json file.